# Function template to run on collections, which has a default "transform" function which does nothing

Tags: c++, templates

I wrote a `Join` function for collections, which allows you to create a joined string for any string like class which supports the `<<` operator. I want to template it so that if your collection isn't a bunch of strings, you can pass a transform function which returns a const reference to the "stringified" field you want.

I haven't been able to figure out how to make this a single function template, and still have this work with collections which are native arrays.

I would want `FunctStringer` to default to an identity function which takes `Collection::value_type` in the case of standard collections, but that would also work with native arrays.

Ideas? Here is the template code:

```
    // Collection::value_type must be able to be streamed into "output"
    template<typename Collection, typename Delimiter, typename Output>
    void Join(const Collection &collection, const Delimiter &delimiter, Output &output)
    {
        if (!std::empty(collection))
        {
            auto iter = std::begin(collection);
            // output the first item
            output << *iter;
            iter++;

            for ( ;iter != std::end(collection); iter++)
            {
                output << delimiter;
                output << *iter;
            }
        }
    }

    // Collection::value_type must be able to be streamed into "output"
    template<typename Collection, typename Delimiter, typename Output, typename FunctStringer>
    void Join(const Collection &collection, const Delimiter &delimiter, Output &output, FunctStringer s)
    {
        if (!std::empty(collection))
        {
            auto iter = std::begin(collection);
            // output the first item
            output << s(*iter);
            iter++;

            for (; iter != std::end(collection); iter++)
            {
                output << delimiter;
                output << s(*iter);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: C++ standard algorithms use iterators rather than collections. Their purpose is *not* to make your life harder. Quite the opposite. You should use iterators and standard algorithms too, to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: (Cont'd) [Demo](https://ideone.com/q0RBLy). This is just std::transform.

Comment: @n.m. Your version with `std::transform` can't insert a delimiter **only** between tokens, this is a known shortcoming of printing collections with standard ostream iterators. Try using `,` as an iterator and you will see a very ugly output.

Comment: @n.m. Also requirement to use iterator for standard algorithm (instead of a container) is nowadays acknowledged shortcoming of standard algorithms, because it requires to you specify the thing twice - thus increasing noise as well as potential for errors. A solution which takes a container and automatically grabs it's iterators is superior.

Comment: @SergeyA this is not a shortcoming of the algorithm, this is a shortcoming of ostream_iterator. I have a custom iterator that works with the comma. It's very easy to write one. I have no idea who are those people who "acknowledge shortcomings" of standard algorithms. Wake me up when they create something better.

Comment: @n.m. ranges anyone?

Comment: The reason to take iterators instead of collections, is so you can take a "cut", i.e. you don't have to start at "begin" and finish at "end". Though I'm a fan of using ranges for that.

Comment: @n.m. it's also about readability of the code. I prefer this, [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/HyusBw_OE), to a handful of std::transform code that doesn't work unless I create my own ostream iterators. Plus, this works well as long as I create adapters for any outputs. For instance, if the output of the Join is going into an ATL CString, I can just create an adapter which gives it the << operator.

Comment: @SergeyA ranges are good. Ranges are a level of abstraction above iterators (not above collections). I'm not terribly familiar with them yet though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question, why not something like

```
struct NoOpStringer {
    template<class ARG> const ARG& operator()(const ARG& arg) {
         return arg;
    }
}
```

and then

```
template<typename Collection, typename Delimiter, typename Output, typename FunctStringer = NoOpStringer>
void Join(const Collection &collection, const Delimiter &delimiter, Output &output, FunctStringer s = FunctStringer{})
```

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I will never learn to use those pesky thans correctly!

Comment: English language is a _pesky beast_, yes ;)

Comment: I swear I tried this and it didn't work because compiler complained that it couldn't deduce FuncStringer. I'll again in IdeOne and post results.

Comment: Well, that worked. I swear I tried something like that. I wish I had kept the error I was getting, and the code that didn't work.... Thanks!

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ - What is a "thans"?

Comment: @bpeikes my initial answer had incorrectly used 'than' instead of 'then', and it was corrected by πάντα ῥεῖ.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution based on a `static const` lambda function for the identity function.

Unfortunately require C++14 (uses generic lambda) but, as you can see, I've also modified the function to use ranged-for loop so doesn't needs iterators anymore and works also for C-style arrays.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

static const auto l = [](auto item){ return item; };

template <typename C, typename D, typename O, typename F = decltype(l)>
void Join (C const & c, D const & d, O & o, F f = l)
 {
   bool  first { true };

   for ( auto const & item : c )
    {
      if ( first )
         first = false;
      else
         o << d;

      o << f(item);
    }

 }

int main()
 {
   std::vector<int>  v1 { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17 };

   int  v2[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

   Join(v1, ',', std::cout);

   std::cout << std::endl;

   Join(v2, ',', std::cout, [](auto i){ return i+10; });

   std::cout << std::endl;
 }
```